# SQL Order By blanks at bottom when the main order by is a Case statement?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I'd like to ORDER BY listing items that are blanks at the bottom of the result, however the main order by is a case statement.

So, my main Order By clause is this:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN pub = 1 THEN title ELSE t.othertitle END;
```

To that, I'd like to apply the following CASE so that blanks go to the bottom:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN (above case) = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Problem is I cannot embed CASE statements.

How would this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show some sample input and the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify your DBMS, so this is ANSI SQL:

```
ORDER BY nullif(CASE WHEN pub = 1 THEN title ELSE t.othertitle END, '') NULLS LAST
```

Comment: This works and is the simplest solution of the ones offered. Thanks horse , et al.

Answer (score 0):

You can in fact embed case statements

```
ORDER BY CASE COALESCE(CASE pub WHEN 1 THEN title ELSE t.othertitle END, '') WHEN '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this explicitly:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN pub = 1 AND title = '' THEN 1
               WHEN pub <> 1 AND t.othertitle = '' THEN 1
               ELSE 2
          END) DESC,
         (CASE WHEN pub = 1 THEN title ELSE t.othertitle END)
```

Comment: the first order by is fine. however, there will still be empty strings as a result of the second `case` expression. in that case the desired ordering is lost.

Comment: @vkp . . . I don't understand the comment.  The second `order by` key *is* the main key mentioned in the question.

Answer (score -2):

Case statements can only(?) be included in Order by when structuring it to return an INT. Create any kind of ordering logic you'd like but make sure it returns an INT in ascending order:

```
order by
(case when pub = 1 then 1
      when pub is null or pub = '' then 2
      else 3 end)
```

Comment: "*Case statements can only(?) be included in Order by when structuring it to return an INT*" - that's plain wrong.